# Populate Account lookup field on Opportunity in the custom object(BO__c)

Tags: trigger

I have created a trigger to create a new BO__c(BO__c is a custom object and having a lookup relation with Opportunity) record upon closing the opportunity(i.e Opportunity stage equal to Closed/Won), and it's working fine. Now I want to auto-populate custom Account__c lookup field in Opportunity on BO__c custom object, can any one help me here. Here is my code where I tried to get the Account__c field in Opportunity into BO__c object as BO_Account__c.

```
trigger Create_New_BO on Opportunity(after insert, after update)
{
try{
    List<BO__c> lstintop = new List<BO__c>();

//Loop for each new and closed won opportunities
    for(Opportunity opty: Trigger.new)
    {
     if((Trigger.oldMap == null ||'Closed Won' != Trigger.oldMap.get(opty.Id).StageName) && (opty.StageName == 'Closed Won') && (opty.OpportunityWon__c == False) )
      {
        BO__c bo_opt = new BO__c();  

          bo_opt.opportunity__c = opty.id;
//        bo_opt.BO_Account__c = opty.Account.Name;(unable to get Account lookup field into newly creaed BO__c record here)
          bo_opt.Name = opty.Name;
          bo_opt.Commission__c = opty.Commission__c;
          bo_opt.Amount__c = opty.Amount;
          bo_opt.Category__c = opty.Category__c;

          bo_opt.Brands__c = opty.Brands__c;


        lstbo_op.add(bo_opt);
      }


    }
insert lstbo_op;
if(System.test.isRunningTest())
          {
                integer i = 10/0;
          }

}catch(Exception ex){
system.debug('An exception occured in trigger named "Create_New__BO" and the exception is::'+ex);
}


}
```

Comment: What's the data type of `BO_Account__c` custom field?

Comment: It's also a lookup field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the following line:

```
//        bo_opt.BO_Account__c = opty.Account.Name;(unable to get Account lookup field into newly creaed BO__c record here)
```

to:

```
bo_opt.BO_Account__c = opty.AccountId;
```

AccountId should populate with the Account's Id.

Comment: Thank you!! @crmprogdev for the quick response, but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: When you say "its not working", what part of it isn't working? Try adding a system.debug at that line to check the value of `opportunity.account` to see why the lookup is not working. You could try `opporutnity.account.Id`, but that shouldn't be necessary. You shouldn't need to query for the Id.

Comment: Here is debug log for the account assignment, looks like it's assigning null value.       17:53:15:035 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [27]|this.BO_Account__c|null|0x33f7d20e

Comment: I just looked it up and edited my answer. The correct field is what I'd originally answered with and then edited. LOL. Use the `Opportunity.AccountId` field. My apologies for leading you astray. That should resolve the issue.